# Creating New Conda Environment for Data Science

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, anaconda

Kindly guide me through the exact set of commands using which I can create a new conda environment in a CentOS Linux 7, with CUDA version 11.2
This environment should definitely contain the following packages:

1. Tensorflow (with GPU support)
2. Pytorch (with GPU support)
3. Scikit-learn
4. Pandas
5. Jupyter
6. Matplotlib

I tried the following:
conda create -n generic tensorflow-gpu pytorch-gpu
conda activate generic
conda install scikit-learn pandas jupyter matplotlib

This however didn't work and threw up a lot of unresolvable dependency conflicts.

Comment: Which channels do you have set up? Include the output of `conda info` to your question